# Onelogin Token scopes API

Tags: onelogin

Is there an API endpoint to check what a certain token granted scopes are?

In order to perform an action for example user delete, the manage all token scope is needed. For better implementation, if we can check the token scopes and only send request when the needed scope is given.

Comment: Can you form the question in elaborated way? What exactly you are trying and what do you need?

Comment: Hey @MayurDighe We are trying to understand if a token that someone has created/granted for our use has the appropriate scopes for our purposes. For example, if we need to remove a user trough API we need to have Manage All scope, but if that has not been granted the call will fail. We would like to be able to check what are the scopes granted so we do not make unnecessary and failing calls. Is that more clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the below link documentation from OneLogin.
In case of only Users, you can select **Manage Users** and for managing all other objects, select **Manage All**. For other scopes refer to the document.

https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/getting-started/working-with-api-credentials